# Can I return a 504 HTTP code in ASP net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

Currently I have an `ExceptionFilterAttribute` to handle exceptions on `controllers`. My API connects to a service (via proprietary TCP/IP). If this service is not reachable I want to return a HTTP 504 response code with a proper error message.

I have figured out how to send a 400

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    if (!MyService.IsConnected)
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new ResultInformation() { ResultCode = 2000056, Message = "My service is not reachable" });

    }
    else
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new ResultInformation() { ResultCode = 0, Message = context.Exception.Message });
    }
}
```

How can I change this code to send a 504 and the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and set the status code manually.

```
//... omitted for brevity

if (!MyService.IsConnected) {
    var info = new ResultInformation() { 
        ResultCode = 2000056, 
        Message = "My service is not reachable" 
    };
    context.Result = new ObjectResult(info) {
        StatusCode = 504
    };
}

//... omitted for brevity
```

Most of the standard status result types that require an object body are in fact derived from `ObjectResult` where they set their specific status code. For example [`BadRequestObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.badrequestobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

If you do not need to actually return a response body, you can instead use [`StatusCodeResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.statuscoderesult?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(504);
```

Comment: This is your answer here. When you need a response body and no other more specific result type will do, use `ObjectResult` and set the status code manually. If you do not need to actually return a response body, though, you can just use `StatusCodeResult`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'll add in that second part as additional info that will be useful to the op

Comment: That worked like a charm. BTW I used the `StatusCodes` enum instead of 504

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 504;
```

Comment: This doesn't really help the OP in their particular scenario. They need to return some sort of `IActionResult`, but don't know which is best. Setting the response status code directly will be potentially overridden by the eventual result type they return.